# How to create a collection from a query in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an existing collection where I can do some queries on. For further data processing, it would be handy to create some subset collections via query.

I understood that I can use the aggregate function with $match and $expr to e.g. $group some values and at the end use $out to get a new collection with the results.

The thing I am hanging on is not to $group anything, but just put the objects that $match finds into a new collection only. So not the complete objects with all their values. Just the one I am matching. Like when you db[collection].find({$match: {...}}, {"key1": 1, "key2": 0})

Where I get the new matching objects just containing key1: value1 but not key2: value2, which is also in the original collection.

How do I achieve that using aggregate without grouping anything? I read through the documentation and couldn't find any other stage operation that looks good.

Comment: [project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)? if i understood you correctly, if not it could be nice if you give an example of an input doc and an output doc the way you required.

Comment: @tomslabbaert you are a life saver tom! thank you. go ahead and write an answer and i ll check it as resolved. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i mentioned in the comments [$project](https://www.google.com/search?q=%24project&oq=%24pr&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i61j69i57j0l3.653j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is the right operator to use to achieve this.